# Android - Saving file to internal memory

Tags: android, memory, internal

I have file in Assets and I need to write this file to the Internal memory (not to the private part as a /data/data/mypackage/files, but to the memory I am able to see as a removable disk, when I am connected to PC). Is there any way how to achieve this? I don't mean the method for file copy, but how to access my internal memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a discussion that answers this problem. I'm assuming that you want to copy your asset to the SD card.

[How to copy files from 'assets' folder to sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain about what you are asking, it sounds like you want to write to the SD card, but that's also usually considered external memory.  If this is what you mean though, here is the documentation you need to read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal